# Что делать с псевдонаучными ответами?

Tags: обсуждение

Периодически в сообществе появляются ответы, основанные на народной или псевдонаучной этимологии. Людям, разбирающимся в языке, в этом случае, как правило, всё понятно, но новичок может их принять всерьёз. Надо отметить, что подобные ответы встречаются даже у опытных пользователей, в компетентности которых не приходится сомневаться.

Какие у вас будут предложения по решению данной проблемы?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я считаю, что подобные ответы следует минусовать и оставлять комментарии-опровержения. В полемику при этом лучше не вступать. Право на неверный ответ имеет каждый, да и определение какой ответ верный, а какой нет, зачастую субъективно. Поэтому я считаю, что если такой ответ и удалять, то только кворумом сообщества из 5 пользователей, а не решением одного модератора.
Если вы считаете, что ответу или вопросу не место в нашем сообществе, то нажмите кнопку "удалить" ("закрыть") под ним, и если ещё 4 пользователя или модератор с вами согласятся вопрос будет удалён.

Как показывает практика, "фрикам" наше сообщество быстро надоедает, а их ответы внизу списка почти никто не увидит. Тоже самое касается случая, когда такой ответ даёт уже опытный участник (бывало и такое).

Другое дело, если появилось несколько аккаунтов, продвигающих псевдолингвистику и плюсующих друг друга. В этом случае без модераторов не обойтись.

Comment: Соглашусь. Возможно даже стоит прямо в тексте ставить отметку ***недостоверно!*** или что-то подобное.

Comment: Поэтому я и перестала отвечать на вопросы и участвовать в обсуждении. Не скажу, что сильна в языкознании, но иногда такие ответы дают (и что интересно - их принимают!), что не хочется спорить и что-то кому-то доказывать.  Лучше "отойти в сторону".

Comment: @user183861 принимают подобные ответы крайне редко, я за свою почти 5-летнюю историю пребывания в сообществе и десятка подобных сообщений не вспомню. В  любом случае, вопросы по этимологии можно игнорировать (можно отправить все вопросы с меткой "этимология в игнор) и отвечать про пунктуацию и орфографию, где псевдоэкспертов почти нет.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Добавлю, что если вопрос явно «вредительский», то есть намеренно вводит в заблуждение или является спамом, его следует отметить тревогой «спам» или требует «вмешательства модератора». Спам нужно удалять!