# Любительская этимология на нашем форуме

Tags: обсуждение

Я хотел бы привлечь внимание участников к этому вопросу с целью оградить нашу площадку от распространения информации и мнений, носящих ненаучный и, особенно, лженаучный характер.

На нашем форуме случаи любительской этимологии встречается довольно часто. Я бы разделил их условно (для удобства в этом обсуждении) на три группы:

1. Конспирология + идеология. Признаки: тайные/сакральные знания; истина в последней инстанции; резко эмоциональная защита какой-то идеологической установки.
2. Ссылки на источники сомнительного качества, где этимологические рассуждения проводятся с нарушением базовых принципов наук о языке.
3. Интеллектуальные упражнения, использующие эрудицию и глубину познаний в других областях, кроме, собственно, этимологии, но не нарушающие базовых принципов п.2.

Пункт 1 нам не грозит — редкие набеги отдельных представителей этого направления успешно вычищаются, шансов набрать минимум очков для комментирования у носителей этого вируса нет.

С пунктом 3 тоже всё достаточно понятно — пока среди постоянных участников не появятся профессиональные лингвисты, работающие или работавшие в области этимологии (а я надеюсь, что когда-то это произойдёт), с этим не следует бороться. Важно только дать возможность случайным посетителям понять, что высказываемая версия является собственной, а не общепринятой.

Основное внимание хотелось бы уделить п.2. Я приведу несколько критериев А.Зализняка (они были в одной из его лекций, но я сейчас просто вопользуюсь статьёй ["Любительская лингвистика"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) в Википедии.

1. Звук А может переходить в звук В — без уточнения языка и периода времени.
2. Гласные не имеют значения, существен только «костяк согласных».
3. Слово А получилось в результате обратного прочтения слова В.
4. Такая-то древняя надпись из той или иной страны читается по-русски.
5. Работа с современным языком, невзирая на то, что века назад он был другим.
6. Игнорирование состава слова. Носитель смысла — корень слова, и он намного важнее, чем приставка или окончание.

Я призываю всех участников не использовать ссылки, подпадающие под критерии п.2. Также я попрошу с пониманием относиться к ситуации, когда я (или кто-то из участников) будет минусовать ответ в таких случаях и отсылать автора к этому обсуждению.

Если у кого-то будут другие мнения, пожелания, дополнения предлагаю их тоже обсудить.

Comment: Вопрос на Мете схожей тематики https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208/Что-делать-с-псевдонаучными-ответами/209#209

Comment: @МаркИз Действительно. Я в те времена не следил за Метой, а сейчас не заметил того обсуждения (из-за того, что мыслил и формулировал другими словами). Я решил обозначить основные пункты для борьбы и при случае ссылаться на это обсуждение (я говорю о ситуации, когда достойный участник допускает подобную ошибку). Конечно, это можно было сделать ответом в том обсуждении.

Comment: @МаркИз да, мне тоже ваш вопрос пришел в голову, но тут даны некоторые критерии (признаки?) и сделан акцент именно на этимологии.

Comment: @Aer я и не ставлю автору что-то в вину, но  иметь ссылку на тот вопрос в этом, будет полезно.

Comment: @МаркИз а я тоже никому ничего не вменяю ) ссылка действительно полезна!